# Add another static IP address that has ports 80 and 443 available linux nginx

Tags: networking, server, nginx

I am running a mail server called [Postal](https://github.com/atech/postal/).

[Following their instructions for the click and open tracking](https://github.com/atech/postal/wiki/Click-&-Open-Tracking), I must add another static IP address that has ports 80 and 443 available.

What must I do to my ubuntu / nginx configuration to do this, say for example to do this on address 10.1.0.12?

I've tried adding this:

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 10.1.0.12:80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    listen 10.1.0.12:443 ssl;
    root /opt/postal/app/public;
}
```

But if I do ping 10.1.0.12 in my server, it comes back

```
PING 10.1.0.12 (10.1.0.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Which makes me think it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

After short overview, I assume that `postal` has own web server and phrase `To avoid conflict with your management interface, you will need another static IP address that has ports 80 and 443 available` means that your server should have another IP address configured (another ethernet interface or IP alias).

For solve your problem I propose to configure nginx as reverse proxy for `postal`.
In this case you need to set listen interface for `fast_server` in `postal.yml`

```
fast_server:
  enabled: true
  bind_address: 127.0.0.1
  port: 5000  # or any other you like
```

Then configure nginx to forward queries to `postal`. Use sample configuration file for nginx: https://github.com/atech/postal/blob/master/resource/nginx.cfg

NB! Do not forget to set:

1. Correct domain names for both virtual hosts in nginx
2. Correct paths to existing certificate and private key for HTTPS host

these are **mandatory** for correct work.